# How to add 2 new properties to each array item within my object

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to add 2 new properties to each array item within my object before saving it to the state. I need to add Value & Label properties to the Declarations array with the value of the Declarations.countryName. Tried the code below, but not to sure how to achieve this:

```
  public getProfile() {
    axios
    .post('https://func-portal-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetUserProfile',
    {
      "EmailAddress": "benn.king@erfdfd.co.uk"
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('Profile.data:', res.data);
      this.setState({profile: res.data.map(p => {
        return {
          ...p,
          // New properties I am trying to create
          p.Declarations.Value: p.Declarations.countryName,
          p.Declarations.Label: p.Declarations.countryName,
        }
      })
    })})
    // Error catching
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```js
public getProfile() {
        axios
            .post('https://func-portal-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetUserProfile',
                {
                    "EmailAddress": "benn.king@erfdfd.co.uk"
                })
            .then(res => {
                console.log('Profile.data:', res.data);

                let profileData = {...res.data};
                 profileData.Declarations = res.data.Declarations.map((item)=>{
                     const newDec = {...item}
                     newDec.Value = item.countryName;
                     newDec.Label = item.countryName;
return newDec
                 })

                this.setState(profileData)
                
                })})
            // Error catching
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }
```

Comment: Hmm Declarations now is an array containing undefined for both items. I am trying to rejig your code to make it work now

Comment: My bad. It should have been item.countryName ..... I have edited my answer. Can you check it again?

Comment: I did notice that little bug and fixed it. But still returning undefined with new code :(

Comment: That's because we didn't return the newDec object. Updated

Comment: Haha that must be it! Testing now